# Stylling Button in WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml, styles

I have a **style** for `button` as per below code.

```
<Style TargetType="Button" x:Key="TransparentButton">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                <Border HorizontalAlignment="Center" x:Name="borderTemplate"
                        Background="Transparent">
                    <ContentPresenter/>
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                        <Setter TargetName="borderTemplate"
                                Property="Border.BorderBrush" Value="Gray" />
                        <Setter TargetName="borderTemplate"
                                Property="Border.BorderThickness" Value="1" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="true">
                        <Setter TargetName="borderTemplate"
                                Property="Border.BorderBrush" Value="Lime" />
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

I need to set the `background` of `button`

1.To **gray** as soon as “**MouseUp**“ event occurred.

2.And set it to Default(say white)as soon as Focus Of Button **being changed** or say **Focus  Being lost.**

**Is there any way to solve this using `Trigger` or `EventTrigger`??.**

---

See One **example** for above code with image

**Button with Above style.**

```
 <Button Background="Black" Style="{StaticResource TransparentButton}"
         Content="0123456789" Height="15" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
         Name="button2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="70,17,0,0" />
```

Button will **look as per below image** after above **style being applied.**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done by using RadioButton instead of Button
just have a look at this

```
<Style x:Key="RadioButtonStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type RadioButton}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#F4F4F4"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource CheckBoxStroke}"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type RadioButton}">
                 <Border  HorizontalAlignment="Center" x:Name="borderTemplate" Background="Transparent" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                            <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                        </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="borderTemplate" Value="#FFE4E4E4"/>
                        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" TargetName="contentPresenter" Value="Center"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="borderTemplate" Value="#FFA1A1A1"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <StackPanel/>
    <RadioButton Content="RadioButton" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="116,86.04,0,0" Style="{StaticResource RadioButtonStyle1}"/>
    <RadioButton Content="RadioButton" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="116,106,0,0" Style="{StaticResource RadioButtonStyle1}"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Thanks for giving Answer....I have tried this code..but what happen with it is...as soon as i pressed a mouse on button...it will set `Border` to Lime and `Background` to Gray....**What should be is??** `Background` should be Gray when `MouseUP` Events occure...thanks.......

Comment: for demo you can see DATA PAGER control of SilverLight....here is [DEMO](http://www.kunal-chowdhury.com/2010/12/paginating-records-in-silverlight.html)..you can see over there..navigate to Demo Section in that article....Thanks......

Comment: i have updated my answer with RadioButton instead of Button style please have a look

Comment: Thanks..for answering.....BUT here what happen after changing ,, All the button becomes `Gray` except..selected one.. ...Thanks...

Comment: Thank you so much for answering...but...  i could not find the StaticResource `CheckBoxStroke`  **<Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource CheckBoxStroke}"/>**
 i have set it to   **<Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Lime"/>**.....though Border is not Changed when mouse is Pressed over the button....

Comment: I have try following code though not getting   **<Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="false">
                                    <Setter Property="Border.BorderBrush" Value="Lime"/>
                                </Trigger>**